# admin-on-rest how to implement a custom saga for auto-refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, admin-on-rest

In the example provided in the aor-realtime [readme](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-realtime)

```
import realtimeSaga from 'aor-realtime';

const observeRequest = (fetchType, resource, params) => {
    // Use your apollo client methods here or sockets or whatever else including the following very naive polling mechanism
    return {
        subscribe(observer) {
            const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                fetchData(fetchType, resource, params)
                    .then(results => observer.next(results)) // New data received, notify the observer
                    .catch(error => observer.error(error)); // Ouch, an error occured, notify the observer
            }, 5000);

            const subscription = {
                unsubscribe() {
                    // Clean up after ourselves
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    // Notify the saga that we cleaned up everything
                    observer.complete();
                }
            };

            return subscription;
        },
    };
};

const customSaga = realtimeSaga(observeRequest);
```

`fetchData` function is mentioned, but it's not accessible from that scope, is it just a symbolic/abstract call ?

If I really wanted to refresh the data based on some realtime trigger how could i dispatch the data fetching command from this scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it is a symbolic/abstract call. It's up to you to implement `observeRequest`, by initializing it with your restClient for example and calling the client methods accordingly using the `fetchType`, `resource` and `params` parameters.

We currently only use this saga with the [aor-simple-graphql-client](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-simple-graphql-client) client

Comment: But If i used `restClient` directly, it woud not update the UI (the currently shown record/list). 
I think i should dispatch a `CRUD_GET_LIST` action (for the case of list view). How can i dispatch such redux action from the context of a realtime saga ?

Comment: To be more clear, I'm trying to add an auto-refreshing functionality to the json rest-client by using websockets.

Comment: When you call `observer.next` with the new data, the saga will call the appropriate action type (either `CRUD_GET_LIST_SUCCESS` or `CRUD_GET_ONE_SUCCESS`.

Btw, I also updated the README for https://github.com/marmelab/aor-realtime to use an existing client